# Move alias command to the background when password is requested

Tags: terminal, alias, background-process, user-input

I prepared an alias to start my tightvnc viewer:

```
alias vnc='/usr/bin/xtightvncviewer MOC'
```

It worked. It asked me for the password and ran the vnc. But it prevented to put next commands in the same terminal window so I tried to move the process to the background.

When I simply add ampersand like this

```
alias vnc='/usr/bin/xtightvncviewer MOC&'
```

it did not display the request for the password and when I typed the password it displayed the error message

```
mann@debian:~$ vnc
[3] 4460
mann@debian:~$ Connected to RFB server, using protocol version 3.8
Enabling TightVNC protocol extensions
Performing standard VNC authentication
p4ssw0rd
bash: p4ssw0rd: command not found

[8]+  Stopped                 /usr/bin/xtightvncviewer MOC
```

How to modify the alias to let it ask for the password and go to the background then?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How to do that depends on where the password is coming from.

If it is to be interactively provided by the user then you just run

```
/usr/bin/xtightvncviewer MOC
```

and after having entered the password the user would put the process into the background by pressing `^Z` and then typing `bg %%`.

If the password is supposed to be provided by the script via `stdin` or the terminal (with `expect` or the like) then you put the whole pipeline in the background:

```
echo password | /usr/bin/xtightvncviewer MOC &
```

Comment: Password is not supposed to be provided by the script via stdin or the terminal. The first advice worked.